# How change characteristics of the bodies manually?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, textures

I have some body which grows. I added this body to the world.

```
...
someBody = world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);
someFixture = tapBody->CreateFixture(&someFixtureDef);
...
```

I think I do not need to paste all code here.

So I added body to the world. The question is how to change position, restitution... of the body which is already in the world? Am I allowed to do that **here**? (because I am getting errors when I try to change something in the `tick` method).

```
-(void) tick: (ccTime) dt
{
    world->Step(dt, velocityIterations, positionIterations);
    for (b2Body* b = world->GetBodyList(); b; b = b->GetNext())
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe instead of destroying and recreating the entire body you could accomplish what you need by destroying and creating a new fixture...

```
for (b2Body* b = world->GetBodyList(); b; b = b->GetNext())
{
    // This assumes you only have one fixture
    b2Fixture* f = b->GetFixtureList();
    f = f->GetNext();

    // Code here to create a new fixture/shape with different size (or whatever)

    // Destory old fixture and create new one
    b->DestoryFixture(f);
    b2Fixture* someFixture = b->CreateFixture(&someFixtureDef);

}
```

Sorry for any typos... haven't tested any of this...

Answer (score 1):

First in the tick method make sure that you are setting the velocity and position iterations and then look through all of the bodies altering them:

```
-(void)update:(ccTime)dt {
    int32 velocityIterations = 8;
    int32 positionIterations = 3;
    world->Step(dt, velocityIterations, positionIterations);

    for(b2Body *b = world->GetBodyList(); b != NULL; b = b->GetNext()) {
       //Do something with the body for example: b->ApplyLinearImpulse...();
    }
}
```

Look at the methods in box2d documentation to move a box2d body, for example->ApplyLinearImpuse ->ApplyForce...If you want to explicitly set the position and angle, then look at ->SetTransform()

I hope this helps!
Tams

Comment: Thanks, but i use these methods) They can only change the position of the body, give some forse,etc. I need to change the size of the shape of the body. (b2CirlceShape shape; shape.m_radius = ... This i use when i create object, and can i update radius somehow?). I have the **growing object** and i want to know how to do that)

Comment: I had to resize a sprite in my application using a pinch gesture that was attached to a b2Body. What I ended up doing was destroying and recreating a new body for every iteration of the pinch. It was very fast and worked well. Perhaps that can work for you.

Comment: Really thanks) As i understood to destroy the body and crete it again in each iteration is the only decision..